# How revisions control works on quora? Database design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, version-control, relational-database

Well, I've seen some plugins to create a versions table to keep track of modifications on specific models, but cant do easily like quora shows

[image: Changing a topic photo on quora]

What I have so far is a table like that:

- **id**
- **item_type**: especifies what model revision refers: "Topic"
- **item_id**
- **event**: if it was: "edited, added, reverted, removed"
- **who**: who triggered the event
- **column**: What column in "Topic" the value has changed. "topic.*photo_url*"
- **new**: new value: "http://s3.amazonaws.../pic.png"
- **old** old value: ""http://s3.amazonaws.../oldpic.png"
- **revision_rel**: points to the past revision
- **timestamp**

[image]

Someone could give me some help and guidelines with this design? Im worried about performance, wrong columns, missing columns, etc

```
id  | item_type | item_id |  event  |    who    | column |   new      |    old     | revision_rel |  date
________________________________________________________________________________________________________
1   |   Topic   |    2    |  edit   |   Luccas  |  photo | pic.png    | oldpic.png |    null      |  m:d:y
2   |   Topic   |    2    |  revert |   Chris   |  photo | oldpic.png | pic.png    |      1       |  m:d:y
```

Comment: You probably do not need this anymore... but you do might not need to store the old and the new value if you record all the events (create, edit, destroy). The old value of version 2 is the new value of version 1.
Depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

There are some gems available that already do what you are looking for. Have you looked into:

Take a looks at existing gems:
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning

I am using audited (previously acts_as_audited) for something very similar:
https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

Comment: I will edit my question later to say that this plugins doesnt do what I need. I want versioning by column, and not the entire row. I will describe this better later and how im implementing. But thanks for the answer.